# Replace LEFT JOIN with WHERE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have DB with 4 tables. I have to use 3 of them.

Is it possible to change `LEFT JOIN` statements with only `WHERE` statement?

Database scheme
[image: DB scheme]

My code block with `LEFT JOIN` statements:

```
FROM        reader
LEFT JOIN   copy
ON          reader.nr = copy.reader
LEFT JOIN   book
ON          copy.ISBN = book.ISBN
```

Output on this query is the Personal code | Name | Surname | Taken books count | Taken Pages sum | Taken books cost

Total: 8 rows (data is correct)

I have tried to replace it on my own. I am out of ideas now. I was thinking, that it should work like this:

```
WHERE       copy.ISBN = book.ISBN AND 
            reader.nr = copy.reader AND
            CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN copy.taken AND copy.return
```

Output on this query should be the same. And it is the same, only the data is not correct. There are only 4 rows and there are people that do not have any books taken right now, but they are not displaying in the output.

It do not work like that. Maybe someone who knows better than me could help with this.

**EDIT** I have the correct query with `LEFT JOIN`, but I need to change it to be with `WHERE`.

Correct query with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    reader.personal_code,
    reader.name,
    reader.surname,
    COALESCE(COUNT(copy.reader), 0) AS Taken_books,
    COALESCE(SUM(book.pages), 0) AS Pages_sum,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(copy.reader) > 0
             THEN SUM(COALESCE(book.cost, 15))
        ELSE
            0
    END AS books_cost
    
FROM        reader
LEFT JOIN   copy
ON          reader.nr = copy.reader AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN copy.taken AND copy.return
LEFT JOIN   book
ON          copy.ISBN = book.ISBN
GROUP BY
    reader.personal_code,
    reader.name,
    reader.surname;
```

Comment: Do you mean an INNER JOIN with that WHERE clause? Can't be done. You need UNION ALL and NOT EXISTS too.

Comment: There where clause removes all rows that doesn't fit the criteria, so move the date where to the on clause

Comment: Do you have a correct query now? Why change it? Why not use JOIN?

Comment: Yes, I have the correct query with ```LEFT JOIN```. But I need to change it to be with ```WHERE```

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite it?!? The new query will be bigger, less performant, more error prone. Really bad idea.

Comment: WHERE removes rows, while LEFT JOIN doesn't remove a row but NULLs it the missing data from the "right side" table, so they're not equivalent. And repeating "i need it in where" is not an answer

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` joins the other tables you are using (kinda merges them on in other, using the values from the `FROM` clause table, in this case `reader`). If you omit this, and if you only `SELECT * FROM reader WHERE ...` you will only have the data of the table `reader` and not the other tables (`copy` and `book`) so you wont be able to use `copy.reader`.

So no, this cant be done *only* with `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

the WHERE removes all rows that fit the bill, that includes all that haven't a book at the current date, so move the date comparison to the ON clause

```
FROM        reader
LEFT JOIN   copy
ON          reader.nr = copy.reader AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN copy.taken AND copy.return
LEFT JOIN   book
ON          copy.ISBN = book.ISBN
```

If you really want to use a `WHERE`

You could make

```
(SELECT
    reader.personal_code,
    reader.name,
    reader.surname,
    COALESCE(COUNT(copy.reader), 0) AS Taken_books,
    COALESCE(SUM(book.pages), 0) AS Pages_sum,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(copy.reader) > 0
             THEN SUM(COALESCE(book.cost, 15))
        ELSE
            0
    END AS books_cost
    
FROM        reader
LEFT JOIN   copy
ON          reader.nr = copy.reader 
LEFT JOIN   book
ON          copy.ISBN = book.ISBN
WHERE  CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN copy.taken AND copy.return
GROUP BY
    reader.personal_code,
    reader.name,
    reader.surname)
    
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT
    reader.personal_code,
    reader.name,
    reader.surname,
    COALESCE(COUNT(copy.reader), 0) AS Taken_books,
    COALESCE(SUM(book.pages), 0) AS Pages_sum,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(copy.reader) > 0
             THEN SUM(COALESCE(book.cost, 15))
        ELSE
            0
    END AS books_cost
    
FROM        reader
LEFT JOIN   copy
ON          reader.nr = copy.reader 
LEFT JOIN   book
ON          copy.ISBN = book.ISBN
WHERE  CURRENT_DATE NOT BETWEEN copy.taken AND copy.return
GROUP BY
    reader.personal_code,
    reader.name,
    reader.surname)
```

Comment: Yeah, I see. But is it possible to write query in such way, that ```LEFT JOIN```would not be used here?

Comment: You can not use WHERe as i described already in my answer, the WHERE removes all rows tht don't fit the  criteria, so it must be in the ON clause as there it only affects the join and which rows are tied together

Comment: Is it possible to write ```WHERE```clause with ```ON```?

Comment: the where doesn't belong the ON there only are limitattions, but you can look at my changed answer if that is what you want

Comment: So I guess it is not really possible to do it without any JOIN clauses. Or it is possible, but very unproductive

Comment: no joins are replace by correlated subquery but that quick very very ugly as costs don't depend directly from reader.  so you  need for the costpart make a correlates to get the cost to a isbn and then select only rows that are in the tome frame, so its best to keepo the joins

Answer (score 0):

It does work like that but you use an additional:

```
CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN copy.taken AND copy.return
```

in the second query. That will change the output. Only books that are returned will be in the result list imo

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing that too. If I remove this statement, It only outputs those readers, who had ever take a book at least once. It do not return those, who did not take the book at all.

Comment: (1) Whether or not those books will be included in the result isn't a matter of opinion—I can't quite tell what you mean to say.
(2) "It does work like that" isn't a particularly helpful response, and (without having messed with the queries myself) it's not clear to me how your answer addresses the problem.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
FROM        reader, copy, book
WHERE       (reader.nr = copy.reader or reader.nr not in (select reader from copy))
AND         (copy.ISBN = book.ISBN or copy.ISBN not in (select ISBN from book))
```

Comment: JOIN are around for 30 years now and are sql standard, so you should post answers with comma seperated FROM clauses

Comment: And won't work anyway.